# How can I fix the concurrent requests issue in nodeJS here?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

In a node course, the instructor implements a class called promisequeue to handle specific number of requests at a time and here is the class

```
class PromiseQueue{
        constructor(promises = [], num = 1){
            this.concurrent = num;
            this.total = promises.length;
            this.todo = promises;
            this.running = [];
            this.complete = [];
        }
        graphTasks(){
            var {todo , running, complete} = this;
            logUpdate(`
            
                todo=${todo.map(toX)}
                running=${running.map(toX)}
                complete=${complete.map(toX)}
            `)
        }
        get runAnother(){
            return this.running.length < this.concurrent && this.todo.length > 0
        }
        run(){
            while(this.runAnother){
                const promise = this.todo.shift();
                this.running.push(promise)
                promise.then(() => {
                    this.complete.push(this.running.shift())
                    this.graphTasks();
                    this.run();
                })
                this.graphTasks()
            }
        }
    }
```

My question is : suppose that we add 2 promises at a time to this.running then the second promise resolved first but in this line

```
this.complete.push(this.running.shift())
```

it will the add the first promise to this.complete although it hasn't resolved yet
Is this a mistake or I miss something

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.
If the second promise resolved first the first one would go this.complete while still running and the third would be added to this.running.
so we have one still running in this.complete and one in this.running which guarantee that we have only 2 at a time.
Thanks for anyone tried to solve